# Forward data from unix socket to cups printer

Tags: virtual-machine, printing, socat

I'd like to print out of a VM (KVM/QEMU via virt-manager).
For the VM to host connection there is an emulated parallel port in the VM that should be connected to a Unix Socket.
I tried to create a listen socket with socat, which should then be redirected to a cups printer by typing
`socat unix-listen:/tmp/kvmpr localhost:631/printers/pdf`
which didn't work.

Now that I didn't have time to tinker around more because my customer wanted his machine back, I tried emulating the same thing by setting up a unix listen port that prints to a cups PDF printer, and letting another cups printer (dummy) print to port 9100 who redirects to the created socket. When i do that i get following errors on the one side:

```
socat -d -d tcp4-listen:9100 /tmp/kvmpr
2021/01/20 17:01:43 socat[5523] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:9100
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N accepting connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:36160 on AF=2 127.0.0.1:9100
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N opening connection to AF=1 "/tmp/kvmpr"
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N successfully connected from local address AF=1 "\x7E\x@D\xB9U"
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N successfully connected via <anon>
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] E write(5, 0x55c9ae7f46b0, 3763): Broken pipe
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5523] N exit(1)
```

and this one on the other:

```
socat unix-listen:/tmp/kvmpr TCP:127.0.0.1:631/printers/PDF
2021/01/20 17:02:11 socat[5513] E write(5, 0x55d5325f2930, 8192): Broken pipe
```

I don't know what to do, I can't find anything related to how I send data to cups via something like socat.

A "quick and dirty" solution from my side was letting the parallel port print into a file and then use a script utilizing ghostpdl to output a pdf, but that is just too complicated for the user to execute.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me with my problem, thanks in advance for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered almost the exact issue when dealing with CUPS.

```
2021/02/01 19:19:22 socat[645] E write(6, 0x557e0b9735a0, 8192): Broken pipe
```

My solution is to double the block size of socat each time and test. My situation ends up with `socat -b 65536 ...`.

```
socat -b 16384 ...
...
socat -b 65536 ...
```

Comment: Oh i forgot to reply I'm sorry.
although using cups would be the most logic thing to do i ditched it after the headaches it gave me and instead created a systemd service via a script which calls GhostPDL to convert from PCL to PDF. I am kind of a noob to Linux with printing so I used a method that i could wrap my head around more easily. Thanks for the answer regardless!